# Swift, Loop through JSON returning Null

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

I am trying to loop through a list of bands that I have in a json file (Using Swifty-Json), for some reason when I get down to looping through the names, it returns null.

## Json

Small snippet of the JSON

```
[  
{  
  "Band":{  
     "ID":"1",
     "Name":"The Kooks"
  }
},
{  
  "Band":{  
     "ID":"2",
     "Name":"The Killers"
  }
}
]
```

## Swift Code

```
 for (_, value) in json {
    for (_,band) in value["Band"] {
       for (_,bandname) in band["Name"] {
           print("Band name: \(bandname)")
       }
     }
 }
```

The above code returns:

> Band name: null
>
> Band name: null
>
> Band name: null
>
> Band name: null

When I try this:

```
for (_, value) in json {
   for (_,brand) in value["Band"] {
      print(band)
   }
}
```

I get this result:

> The Kooks
>
> 1
>
> The Killers
>
> 2

Can anyone tell me what the issue is?

Answer (score 1):

Since the value associated with the key "Name" is a simple string, you want to use:

```
for (_, value) in json {
    for (_,band) in value["Band"] {
       if let bandname = band["Name"].string {
           print("Band name: \(bandname)")
       } else {
           print("No name specified")
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: On the if let line, I get this error: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'JSON'

Comment: Then you should probably mention what you're actually using to parse the JSON itself :)

Comment: Is the code above not parsing JSON? I'm sure my question shows that I am looping through and trying to display the Names from the JSON

Comment: Never mind, I missed the "swifty-json" part, which is essentially what I'm asking.

Comment: oh, ok. I am a little nooby so I was worried I used the wrong terminology. Do, you have any idea with swifty-json what is the problem?

Comment: I made some changes that should fix it for you.

Comment: This is returning: "No name specified"